# How can I use an old LCD screen? How can I determine each pin?

Tags: components, lcd

I took apart a broken iHome ip90. I now have the lcd screen, but I want to figure out how to use it in a project or something. I am used to getting nice instructions and tutorials, but obviously it's difficult to find something like that for this LCD. Is there a systematic way (without breaking my arduino) I can use to figure out which pin is which (it has a female bunched up jumper wire)?

Just trying to figure out how I can start using old electronic parts.

Comment: Datasheet. Always the datasheet.

Comment: I tried googling, but its not that easy to find. Any recs?

Comment: see if anyone has used it in a 'hack'

Comment: pictures please

Answer (score 1):

LCD's are almost always custom, with no datasheets available.  This is especially true of LCD's that you find in consumer electronics gear.  If you can't find the information you need with a quick Google search then I'd give up while you're ahead.

I choose to never use any LCD that I don't have the complete datasheet for (not just the datasheet for the controller chip on/in the LCD)-- and I've used a lot of LCDs!  While it is possible to reverse engineer the LCD and figure out how to use it, it is often very time consuming and not worth the effort/bother/etc.

Sorry for the pessimistic outlook, but I've learned this the hard way and hate to see others repeat it.